# How can i replace value in .config file using TFS and Variables Functionality?

Tags: java, visual-studio-2012, tfs, config

How can i replace values in .config file using TFS and Variables Functionality?

I need a way of replacing values within my .config files via MS TFS.

For example if set the 'browser' type to 'firefox' via variables option within tfs then this new value should be populated with the existing .config file which has now been altered.

**My Config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Properties Example</comment>
<entry key="browser">#{chrome}#</entry>
<entry key="url">#{https://www.example.com}#</entry>
<entry key="username">#{joeblogs@example.com}#</entry>
</properties>
```

I need to replace all values which have a #{ replace me }# from the tfs using something like the following setup: [link](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/replace-appsettings-token-configfiles-build-release-tfs-vsts)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a solution. What is preventing you from implementing it?

Comment: @Daniel Mann the setup seems to require a value syntax as illustrated in the exercise, so <entry key="browser">#{chrome}#</entry> would become <entry key="browser" value="#{chrome}#">#{chrome}#</entry> however i need a way to alter the value with solely the following syntax: <entry key="browser">#{chrome}#</entry>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use chrome of **variable name** instead of browser in your TFS variables setting.

Cause the replace token will replace the value  values have a #{ replace me }#, in your case it should be chrome  not browser.

[image]

Besides since you are using xml, you could also use  the `*.xml`  instead of `**/*.config`

Comment: thanks so much for your help!! did the trick, hope you have a great day

Comment: I also need to replace values in webconfig file and also used replaced token tasks for that, but still I have a little confusion, then tokenization implemented on actual main web.Config file which is also used by developers and also added token, if i add test = '#{token}#' than developers will not able to run the application because values changed with  #{}#
Is their any way that we can replace values without 'Replace token'